# angular 4 PWA in production?

Tags: angular, angular-cli, progressive-web-apps

I know the CLI --mobile flag is not working till now and it seems to take forever even with the official release of the CLI (1.0.3) but I started experimenting with `@angular/service-worker` and `@angular-appshell` packages but I still have a really simple question why does the NGSW work only in production mode: `ng build --prod`

Answer (score 2):

You can serve in prod mode using `ng serve --prod`

As the service workers are mainly used to cache your app it can be a real problem if you don't know how to disable the cache properly and force the update on reload. That's why, I guess, they disabled it outside of prod mode.